# How to insert into two table using laravel 8? This is my code

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

This is my code

I have a table `inventory_transactions(id, part_name, part_number)` and `transaction_logs(id, description, inventory_transaction_id(FOREIGN KEY))`. I want to insert the value of id to `inventory_transaction_id`.
What should I do?

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Models\Inventory_transaction;
    use App\Models\Transaction_log;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    public function store(Request $request){
    
    $inventory_transaction = $request->validate($this->validation());       
    $value = Inventory_transaction::create($inventory_transaction);
    return $this->respondWithMessage('Transaction added');
}

private function validation()
{
    return [
    'part_name' => ['required'],
    'part_number' => ['required'], 
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have relationships defined as

```php
class Inventory_transaction extends Model
{
    public function transaction_logs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction_log::class);
    }
}
```

you can use the relation to insert related record

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate($this->validation());

    $transaction = Inventory_transaction::create($validated);

    $transaction->transaction_logs()->create(['description' => 'Transaction Added.']);

    return $this->respondWithMessage('Transaction added');
}
```

Having said that you should seriously spend some time going through Laravel docs, it will enable you to understand the basics very well - Laravel has one of the best documentation with lots of code examples for easy understanding of basic

Laravel relations: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction

Comment: still not working bro. I this in my Inventory_transaction.php model
    public function transaction_logs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction_log::class);
    }

Comment: Pls be more specific what is not working - what results are you getting and how different from the expectation. Are you getting any errors